# DataTable.Select string function in where clause

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I'm having problems with a `DataTable.Select()` where the matching values might contain leading spaces and need to be trimmed correctly to return the correct amount of records.

Currently my code is returning less records as the matching fails because of unwanted characters.

How do you handle DataTable.Select as the example SQL below suggests?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE LTRIM(FullName) = ' Joe Smith'
```

I' tried

```
dataTable.Select("LTRIM(FullName) = ' Joe Smith'");
```

but it failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: As your SQL will fail, too, I'd say your code is correct.

Comment: No intentional spelling to illustrate point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest to use `Linq-To-DataSet` instead, it makes it a lot clearer and easier to maintain:

```
var rows = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
           where row.Field<string>("FullName").Trim() == "Joe Smith"
           select row;
```

If you want to use `LTRIM` instead, you just have to replace `Trim` with [`TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx).

if you want an array or list, use `ToArray` or `ToList`, e.g.

```
DataRow[] rowsArray = rows.ToArray();
```

or a DataTable

```
dataTable = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

**Edit**: if you insist on using `DataTable.Select` or you can't use linq, this should work(`LTRIM` [is not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)):

```
rowsArray = dataTable.Select("TRIM(FullName) = 'Joe Smith'");
```

Comment: +1 This answer is perfect unless the OP  does not want to use `Linq`:)

Comment: So there is nothing specifically for left trim?

Comment: @ConradLotz: You mean as `DataColumn.Expression`-syntax in `DataTable.Select` or in Linq? There is no `LTRIM` support for `DataTable.Select` as i've mentioned and linked, but in Linq you can use all methods of .NET, so also [`String.TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx).

Comment: Note that to use `AsEnumerable()`, you need to add a reference to the `DataTableExtenstions` DLL.

Comment: I recommend the link given https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx  "DataColumn.Expression Property", which lists `CONVERT`, `LEN`, `ISNULL`, `IIF`, `TRIM` and `SUBSTRING` as supported functions.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
string searchTerm = " Joe Smith";
string expression = String.Format("TRIM(FullName) = '{0}'", searchTerm.Trim());
dataTable.Select(expression);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable excelData = objGetExcelData.DataExcel(objEntities.StrFilePath, ConfigSettings.GetAppConfigValue("select * from sheet1"));

StringBuilder strInput = new StringBuilder();
DataView view = new DataView(excelData); 
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "GROUP_NAME"); 
if (distinctValues.Rows.Count > 0)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < distinctValues.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
           strGroupName = Convert.ToString(distinctValues.Rows[i]["GROUP_NAME"]);
           foreach (DataRow item in excelData.Select("GROUP_NAME = '" + strGroupName + "'"))
           {
               strInput.Append(Convert.ToString(item[0]));
               strInput.Append("~");
               strInput.Append(Convert.ToString(item[1]));
               strInput.Append(",");
               strDasID = Convert.ToString(item[0]);
            }
      }
}
```